# вывести картинку js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица динамическая по нажатию на кнопку добавляются поля.
Есть первое поле оно сделано `autocomplete`, а в стольные поля информация подтягивается из базы. что бы информация записывалась в нужное поля я делаю так

`success: function(data){
 $("input.price"+i).val(data);
 }`

для `input` понятно, а как сделать если нужно вставить картинку ?
Если такое можно сделать ?

Comment: Возможно все можно решить через добавление атрибута src для изображения.

Comment: Там где добавляются поля добавлять также элемент `<img>`, затем jquery методом установить аттрибут `src` у этого элемента: `.attr('src',data)`. Тут точнее не ответить.

Comment: Спасибо помогло все работает.